# What would be the best practice implementing Google Adwords Dynamic Remarketing Tag with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-ads-api

I am trying to dynamically populate the google adwords remarketing tag.
This is how the google code looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var google_tag_params = {
dynx_itemid: 'REPLACE_WITH_VALUE',
dynx_itemid2: 'REPLACE_WITH_VALUE',
dynx_pagetype: 'REPLACE_WITH_VALUE',
dynx_totalvalue: 'REPLACE_WITH_VALUE',
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = {converion-id}; // replace {converion-id} with your conversion id
var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
var google_remarketing_only = true;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<!-- replace {converion-id} with your conversion id -->
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/{converion-id}/?value=0&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/> 
</div>
</noscript>
```

On each page loaded I would like to dynamically replace the dynx_itemid variable through angular.
I would love to hear your thoughts about it. I've found the following lib https://github.com/mooyoul/angulartics-google-adwords-remarketing-tag but it supports only the remarketing tag and not the dynamic one.

Thanks

Comment: I think with `angular.js` must implement Asynchronous AdWords Remarketing Tag -> https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/asynchronous/

Comment: Thanks Ahmed for the edit!

Answer (score 0):

Eventually we ended up just creating an angular module that gets three parameters for the conversion label, value and currency and we called it from wherever needed

```
angular.module('project.google.model', [
/*Google Remarketing Module*/
]).service('GoogleModel', [function () {
    var model = this;
    model.trackConversion = function (label, value, currency) {

        window.google_trackConversion({
            google_conversion_id: xxxxxxx,
            google_conversion_language: "en",
            google_conversion_format: "3",
            google_conversion_color: "ffffff",
            google_conversion_label: label,
            google_conversion_value: value,
            google_conversion_currency: currency,
            google_remarketing_only: false
        });
    }
}]);
```